# How do I create an Oracle 11g user with read access to all tables/schemas?

Tags: oracle-11g

I need to create a user that has read access to all the schemas.  Do they just need Select priviliges or is there more that needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can grant `SELECT ANY TABLE`, however, that is seen by some as "excessive" privileges, and should be questioned.

On the plus side, Oracle 11 keeps key system views hidden even from that grant .. so it's not nearly as bad as it once was ;)

It would be best to build `ROLEs` and grant the `SELECTs` to the required tables to the `ROLEs` ... then grant the `ROLE` to your users as needed.

If you haven't yet, you should probably read over this guy:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531.pdf